# Excel data into grid

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-architect

I was just wondering if there is a way to paste data from a excel table into a grid in extjs (sencha). Maybe with the ctrl + v option or a way to load the data from the excel too.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XSLX.js](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/xlsx.js) library to read and write XSLX files, and map the resulting javascript objects to records for your grids. However, I am not sure how to combine that external library with Sencha Architect.